# Bootstrap for Native Civicrm Mobile Use

Tags: mobile, bootstrap

Is there a project to enable Bootstrap in Civicrm to convert Civicrm natively into Mobile View?

Thank you!

Comment: Following. Civicrm would look and feel much better if it used bootstrap

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! It would be helpful if you could say a bit more about what your requirements are.  This will help people to provide better answers.

Answer (score 2):

There is a civi mobile app for Android and iOS. See https://civimobile.agiliway.com/ and https://civicrm.org/blog/skornien/civimobile-a-native-mobile-application-for-civicrm

Comment: Understood & I value the great guidance. Thank you

Comment: The question still remains to make effort Civicrm is Bootstrap 4.x capable for responsive use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is the [Shoreditch extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/shoreditch) which replaces the user interface with a more modern theme based on Bootstrap.